# Is light visible?

Tags: optics, visible-light, vision

I was confused when i saw the rgb spectrum where the light goes on a prism and then we get the colours .. we see the source of the refracted light ? like seeing a blue sun ?

Answer (score 1):

Please don't look at the Sun!  Instead of the Sun, let's look at, a white light bulb.

If you look at a typical white light bulb through a prism or a diffraction grating held in the right way, you will indeed see a blue light bulb. You will also see a red light bulb, and an orange light bulb, and a yellow light bulb, and a continuum of other light bulbs for all of the colors in between.  And all of those colored light bulbs will overlap one another so that they will appear as a smear of color that is redish at one end and blueish at the other.

Not all light bulbs are equal however.  Some supposedly "white" compact fluorescent light bulbs actually emit just a few very narrow wavelengths of light.  If you look at one of those through a prism or a diffraction grating, you will see a few, clear, non-overlapping images of the light bulb in different colors.

But don't take my word for it.  Get a cheap piece of [diffraction grating film](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0074R74D8), or a prism, and try the experiment at home.

But please, don't stare at the Sun.